# Enable Collation on Primary Key column in sql server 2012

Tags: collation

I have a table in sql server 2012 where there is a column that is part of the Primary key. It has a collation set `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` on it. As part of requirement , I need this column to be case-sensitive for which I need to alter the column collation to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE <Table_Name>
ALTER COLUMN <Col Name> <Data Type>
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

As I understand I cannot alter collation on primary key column. Hence , I removed the column from primary key cluster , executed the above Alter collation command and made the column primary key back again. Unfortunately though after executing the alter command the collation changed to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` , it flipped back to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` after I made that column as a primary key.

Would Appreciate if anyone could help me understand why this is occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with GUI. Not sure why but it flips back if we change collation using script.

Delete the primary key --> alter table and change collation --> Using GUI make column not Null --> Using GUI make the column primary key. Collation will not flip back this way.

Hope this helps!